# Using Derby from Groovy

Tags: java, sql, groovy, derby

I'm writing some Groovy scripts to parse my bank statements and load them into a derby db. I'm stuck trying to get a connection to my derby db from Groovy. I'm using [documentation found here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedded+Derby+DB+examples). I'm attempting to add derby to the class path dynamically but it's failing.

```
import java.sql.*

def env = System.getenv()
def sql
try{
    DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true')
}
catch (SQLException se){
    def derbyURL = new File("${env['JAVA_HOME']}/db/lib/derby.jar")
   println "Loading derby: ${derbyURL.exists()}"
   this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(derbyURL.toURL())
   def sqlClass = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.loadClass('groovy.sql.Sql')
   sql = sqlClass."newInstance"("jdbc:derby:cliffdb;")
}
```

From this I get

```
Loading derby: true
Exception thrown
Feb 01, 2014 10:47:38 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StackTraceUtils sanitize
WARNING: Sanitizing stacktrace:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:cliffdb;
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:232)
    at groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at BankStatementReader.run(BankStatementReader.groovy:13)
```

I've tried all variations of Sql.newInstance from directly calling it to loading the Sql class from the root class loader to now loading the Sql class from the current thread context classloader. What am I missing and why does this not work when the Derby jar is indeed present?

** **Update** **

I just moved my Sql loading code into a separate callable class and have transformed my original script into a full IntelliJ Groovy project. The code below is working thanks to the answer provided in the comments below!

```
package com.craig.banking.db

import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException

/**
 * Created by clifton on 2/2/14.
 */
public class DBSqlProvider {
    static groovy.sql.Sql sql;
    def dbProperties = new Properties()
    def env = System.getenv()

    DBSqlProvider() {
        dbProperties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties"))
    }

    def findSql() {
        try{
            DriverManager.getConnection(dbProperties.dbURL)
        }
        catch (SQLException se){
            def derbyURL = new File("${env['JAVA_HOME']}/db/lib/derby.jar")
            println "Loading derby: ${derbyURL}"

            def rootLoader = this.class.classLoader.rootLoader
            rootLoader.addURL(derbyURL.toURL())
            Class.forName('org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver')
            def sqlClass = rootLoader.loadClass('groovy.sql.Sql')
            sql = sqlClass."newInstance"(dbProperties.dbURL)
        }
    }

    def getSql() {
        findSql()
        if (null == sql) {
            sql = groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(dbProperties.dbURL)
        }
        return sql
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you run the script with `-cp derby.jar:.` rather than trying to manipulate the system classloader in the script?

Comment: Yes it does, but I was too lazy to quit my interactive console, update the class path, and start again. I'm actually more interested in why the dynamic part isn't working as expected.

Comment: After dynamically adjusting the classpath, did you try loading the class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver? I think that will, internally, call DriverManager.registerDriver, which is what gives the DriverManager the linkage between the jdbc:derby: url scheme and the EmbeddedDriver JDBC driver.

Comment: Ahhh! Yes, now I remember! I just tried that and it failed as well. I've moved my work from a simple GroovyScript to an established IntelliJ Groovy project. I'll update my question with this attempt.

Comment: Success!!! I had to use the ol' Class.forName() call and not loadClass() to get it working! Wow, it's been a while since I've done this! Please move your comment to an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` for a "Network Server" connection as listed in the Apache Derby documentation linked [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html#ns_lookat_code).